# If I return twice in a function, would the second one overwrite the first one?

Tags: javascript, return

I am writing a function in Javascript. Basically, it should return `true` if the string in the first element of the array contains all of the letters of the string in the second element of the array. I am testing my function on the input `["hello","hey"]`

```
    function mutation(arr) {
      var string1 = arr[0].toLowerCase();
      var array=[];
      for (i=0;i<=string1.length-1;i++) {
        array[i]=string1[i];
      }

      var string2 = arr[1].toLowerCase();

      var result = true;

      label:
      for(i=0;i<string2.length;i++) {
        if (array.indexOf(string2[i]) == -1) {
          result = false;
          break label;
        }
        else {
          result = true;
        }
      }

      return result;

    }
```

This would give me the correct result `false`. However, if I write my loop in a different way, then it would give me `true`.

```
  label:
  for(i=0;i<string2.length;i++) {
    if (array.indexOf(string2[i]) == -1) {
      return false;
      break label;
    }
    else {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

Where did I do wrong in my second method?

Comment: *"Where did I do wrong in my second method?"* As soon as you `return` from a function, it terminates. How should the loop be able to continue to run if control has already been passed back to the caller?

Comment: In the first iteration of the loop you are checking `array.indexOf('h') == -1` which is `false` since `"hello"` contains `"h"`. Because the condition is `false`, the `else` branch is executed where you `return true;` from the function. Again, `return` **terminates** the function.

Comment: @JK Thank you for your advice :)

Answer (score 3):

A `return` statement terminates the function immediately. In the second implementation early returning `false` is indeed correct, but the `return true` statement is wrong - it will return true on the first element isn't contained in the second array. Effectively, you're negating the loop - only the first element is examined, and a value returned immediately.

What you intended here is to early-return only `false` values:

```
for (i = 0; i < string2.length; i++) {
    if (array.indexOf(string2[i]) == -1) {
      return false;
    }
}
// If we finished the loop and haven't returned false, the return value is true:
return true;
```

Comment: I beat you in time but you beat me in completeness.  Yours is better :)

Answer (score 1):

Your second method breaks at this point:

`return true`

The moment the return occurs in a positive match, your FOR loop terminates.

In your initial version, because it is only setting the `result = true`, the `FOR` loop continues, until it encounters a FALSE, then your explicit `BREAK` occurs.

However, in the other version, the if statement will encounter either a `RETURN FALSE` or a `RETURN TRUE`, it will iterate only once, returning a result and ending the FOR loop.

Answer (score -1):

In your first case, the logic was quitted and returned the value `false`, as long as it satisfied the condition `(array.indexOf(string2[i]) == -1)` in your case.

In the second case, the first element of your array didn't satisfy the condition and fell into the `else` condition, thus quitted with `true` returned.

Comment: This isn't analyzed correctly.  I'll withhold the down-vote for now.  The problem isn't with the return false, but with the return true.